# SOLR sort on dynamicField with type string

Tags: string, apache, sorting, solr

I got problem with sort in solr on dynamicField which type is string;

```
<dynamicField name="*_SEARCH"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="false" />
```

result are paging(I got 100 documents; 20 for page), and he sort only first page

for example I get 20 documents with sort by this field with value:

1. 9999.0
2. 9999.0
3. 22222.0
4. 22.2
5. 22.2

   .
   .
   .
6. 10.0
7. 0.0 
   8.

as can You see problem is with the order

sort parameter: (dynamic content)_SEARCH desc

Comment: what is the problem with the order? It is sorting them alphabetically in desc order, since it is a string field.

Comment: Why don't you keep these data into Double type field instead of string?

Comment: This is example data, this field can hold any value and this is why this filed type is string - exacly I want this results in proper order by sort(like when it was be a double field type); this will be return results alphabetically always? without take into consideration length of string ?